# what's the different between Post.title.should == "test" and Post.title should == "test"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using rspec-rails

what's the different between

```
Post.title.should == "test"
```

and

```
Post.title should == "test"
```

thanks

Comment: One has a `.`, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `Post.title should == "test"` is almost certainly incorrect. In this case, `should` is being called on `self`, not on `Post.title`.

Answer (score 0):

It should **not** work.

Assertions like that should be made in this form:

```
Post.title.should =="test"
# or, for prettier imo option:
Post.title.should eq("test")
```

Be aware though, that `be()` matcher is **very** different from `eq`/`equal`/`==` matchers. [Study the docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-8/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers) for the latest RSpec (`v2.8`).